# How to import Delphi's ActiveX(OCX) file in asp.net 2008

Tags: asp.net, delphi, activex

I have created `piechart.ocx`(ActiveX file) in Delphi 6.0, now I want to use it in asp.net 2008.
I had done all the stuff that I was found on internet, I found that it was imported but remain hide in toolbox. how would I display ActiveX control in toolbox and use it in web form.

Date: 11/8/2011

now, i Found that i can use this 'ocx' file is in window application in asp.net, but still remain problem with C# asp.net(Web) application. can any one help.....??